# How to make if statements execute in order?

Tags: python, if-statement, variables

I am making a program, and yet even though I have certain variables who basically contain the same value, they are blocking the approach through an if statement, to execute another if statement.

```
    if check_2.get() == "1":    

    if result_1 or result_1A or result_1B or result_1C or result_1D == True:
        head = pygame.Rect(20, 20, 60, 60)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 50, 50), head)

    elif result_1 or result_1A or result_1B or result_1C or result_1D == False:
        pass

    if result_2 or result_2A or result_2B or result_2C or result_2D == True:
        head = pygame.Rect(80, 80, 60, 60)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 50, 50), head)
        head = pygame.Rect(180, 80, 60, 60)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 50, 50), head) 

    elif result_2 or result_2A or result_2B or result_2C or result_2D == False:
        pass

    if result_3 or result_3A or result_3B or result_3C or result_3D == True:
        head = pygame.Rect(80, 180, 60, 60)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 50, 50), head)
        head_1 = pygame.Rect(180, 280, 60, 60)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 50, 50), head_1)
        head_2 = pygame.Rect(130, 280, 60, 60)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 50, 50), head_2)

    elif result_3 or result_3A or result_3B or result_3C or result_3D == False:
        pass

else:
    print("Sorry")
```

DONT MIND THE INDENTS, they're fine.

For example if I only allow result_1 to be True.....the result_2 and result_3 become undefined and so it does not let me draw a single rect. Would kindly appreciate some help.

Comment: You can not chain comparisons with `or` like that. You have to write them out.

Comment: What is you intent when testing `elif result_1 or result_1A or result_1B or result_1C or result_1D == False:` ? If you are trying to see if any of the variables is `False` then you are not doing it correctly.

Comment: Try `print(result_1)`, `print(result_1A)` and so on, then `print(result_1 or result_1A or result_1B or result_1C or result_1D == True)`. This may help you understand what is happening.

Comment: @AmitaiIrron I want the first if statement to run to check if any of the results come out as True, if not then I want to move onto the second if statement which is for result_2 and so on.

Comment: You should use `elif` and `or`, p.ex: `elif result_1 or result_1A or result_1B or result_1C or result_1D == False: `